# Не могу понять как сделать управление

Tags: android, unity3d

[image: Как сделать управление для этих стрелок]

Как сделать управление для этих стрелок, чтоб работало на андройд?

Comment: А что именно у Вас не получается? Покажите код.

Comment: Я не могу понять просто как сделать

Comment: для начала что они должны сделать при нажатии

Comment: и да используйте знак @ чтобы пользователь видел ваш ответ (пример @Alt_F4)

Comment: @Alt_F4 стрелка вверх должна двигать персонажа вверх, а стрелки вправо и влево поворачивать персонажа вправо и влево

Comment: Подождите немного я напишу этот скрипт для вас.

Answer (score 1):

## Работоспособность

[image]

---

## Код

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;
    readonly float step = 40, angle = 22.5f;

    public void Up()
    {
        Player.transform.Translate(0, step, 0);
    }

    public void Left()
    {
        Player.transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, 0, angle);
    }

    public void Right()
    {
        Player.transform.eulerAngles -= new Vector3(0, 0, angle);
    }
}
```

---

## Окно Inspector

Вот так добавляйте функции к кнопкам.

[image]

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: а как сделать чтоб зажать кнопку вверх и персонаж начал двигаться вверх, а отпустив кнопку он переставал двигаться

Comment: @MrLesnik Будет удобно и это покажу

Comment: покажите пожалуйста

Comment: @MrLesnik прочитайте [тут](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/359106/) всё написано и показано

Comment: все равно не очень понятно

Comment: @MrLesnik для этого создайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: с вами в личку можно связаться?

Comment: @MrLesnik Вот мой [ВК](https://vk.com/just.arman)